# Automatically process text/plain as JSON with Jersey

Tags: java, json, curl, jersey, mime-types

I'm new to [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) and attempting to get automatic JSON processing working with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as per [these instructions](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson).

I have `@GET` and `@POST` working with `application/json`, but I'd like to POST with other mime types such as `text/plain`, mostly so that `curl` works without specifying a header (which I think might require handling `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but for this question I'll stick with `text/plain` for now).

The resource class is:

```
package hellotest;
// omit imports for space

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HelloJson sayHello() {
        return new HelloJson("Hello there!", "buttface");
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HelloJson sayHelloPost(HelloJson h) {
        return new HelloJson(h.getBar() + "p", h.getWhee() + "p");
    }
}
```

The server advertises that `POST`ing `text/plain` is ok:

```
curl -X OPTIONS  http://localhost:8080/auth/rest/hello
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.23.2 2016-08-08 17:14:55"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/auth/rest/">
        <resource path="hello">
            <method id="sayHelloPost" name="POST">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
             -->    <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>   <--
                </request>
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <method id="sayHello" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

However, attempting to post `text/plain` fails (added line breaks for clarity):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d '{"bar": "somebar", "whee": "somewhee"}'
    http://localhost:8080/auth/rest/hello
{"bar":"somebarp","whee":"somewheep"}

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
     -d '{"bar": "somebar", "whee": "somewhee"}'
     http://localhost:8080/auth/rest/hello
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 415</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /auth/rest/hello. Reason: <pre>
             Unsupported Media Type</pre></p><hr><a *snip rest of line*

    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What if you add `-H Accept:application/json` in your curl?

Comment: @nilesh `415 Unsupported Media Type` without the xml representation.

Comment: Have you tried `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
     -d 'bar=somebar&whee=somewhee'
     http://localhost:8080/auth/rest/hello`

Comment: @nilesh same result as input in JSON

Comment: so you don't get error anymore. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @nilesh I mean that you get the same result whether you pass the data as json or as url query parameters with text/plain, a 415